# Why does a number that's formatted with .ToString("X4") have characters in it?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
vm.Info0 = phrase.PhraseNum.ToString("X4");
```

What I wanted was for the number to be formatted with some leading zeros like this:

```
00001
00222
00034
```

But instead what I see are some characters 3607 displayed as 0E17

Can anyone tell me what's happening and why it changes the number?

Comment: Because you are asking to view an hexdecimal representation of that value.

Comment: See [Standard Numeric Format String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want decimal number in the output you should use `.ToString("D4");`.

You can check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros).